# How can I create a measure that returns the newest status (non-numerical) in the data set?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have a table in Power Pivot called **tabStatus** (see picture). I want to create a measure for this table that returns the **status_code** (a text field) for the newest status (= highest/newest time stamp in the **status_change** column).

I feel this should be really easy (I am new to DAX). Any ideas as to how I can create this measure?

Appreciate all the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your Status_change column is a valid date/time format in your locale.

```
Newest Status:=CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(tabStatus[Status_code],0),filter(tabStatus,max(tabStatus[Status_change])))
```

Comment: Thank you! The formula seemed to work, but I realized that my data could include multiple statuses with the exact same time stamp which forces me to use another method. Still, your formula was very helpful.